# sObject type '' is not supported - Salesforce Functions

Tags: node-salesforce, salesforce-functions

I am exploring Salesforce Functions in trial org. And with help of documentation i could deploy the functions. But when I try to run the functions i am getting following error -

*sObject type 'Account' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.*

Following are enabled using permission sets/profile:
Compute Access
Compute Production Access
Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is when executing the function in Heroku, you must also authorize the Functions permission set for the queried SObject(s). I talk about that a bit [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRdqe-neM7s&t=105s). Let me know if that doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you Scott! It worked fine. And now i understand it uses Platform Integration user to execute the functions.